# When using DNS from another continent, will IP's and CDN's reflect host country as well?

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, internet, geolocation

Lets say I am using Russia’s Yandex DNS from Canada, or America.

Will I be served IP's and CDN's that reflect the host country of said DNS?

And will they tend to be nearer to that nation?

Comment: Only for as much as the DNS records you request rely on geo DNS. More advanced geo targeting relies more on your ip-address than on how you resolved a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most CDNs use Anycast instead of Unicast, which essentially make the IP that the DNS returns "present" all over the world at once, and your packets gets routed to the nearest node for that IP. This is for example what happens when you "hide" a webserver behind Cloudflare, they return an IP address for their CDN instead of the real IP of your server, and then proxy the traffic to your server.

So, to answer your question, if you browse any modern and large web application, you'll get served by the closest server to you, not your DNS-provider. Also, a DNS provider shouldn't modify the records they return, they should give you a cached copy of what they got the last time they queried the authoritative name server for that record. Anything else would be considered a man-in-the-middle attack. An exception to this is what OpenDNS does, if they can't reach the authoritative name server, they'll serve you with the newest expired record from their cache, thus prioritising availability before absolute accuracy.

Comment: Ok I was assuming it was possible the authoritative name server would be different servers, serving relevant IP's according to the DNS server location. Apparently not! Thank you for you answer!

Comment: There are implementations of that as well, but it has to be done at the authoritative name server, you can't (or more like shouldn't) modify DNS query answers after they've been sent by the authoritative name server.